# Como usar um bloco de código dentro de um bloco de spoiler?

Tags: suporte, markdown

Quando se deseja um bloco de código, colocamos 4 espaços antes do primeiro caracter.

Isso:

```
    CODE CODE CODE
    CODE CODE CODE
```

Se torna isso:

```
CODE CODE CODE
CODE CODE CODE
```

Para fazer citações, devemos colocar um `>` com o espaço logo em seguida.

Isso:

```
> citação
```

Se torna isso:

> citação

Para por bloco de código *dentro* de uma citação, precisamos por o `>` seguido do espaço da citação e, também, os quatro espaços necessários para o bloco de código (totalizando 5 espaços).

Isso:

```
> Código abaixo:
>
>     CODE CODE CODE
>     CODE CODE CODE
```

Se torna isso:

> Código abaixo:
>
> ```
> CODE CODE CODE
> CODE CODE CODE
> ```

O bloco de spoiler é extremamente semelhante ao de citação. Você começa com o `>` da citação, então bota um *bang* `!` e então um espaço em seguida, ficando algo como `>!`

Isso:

```
>! spoiler, Jão das Neves se torna Rei
```

Se torna isso:

> spoiler, Jão das Neves se torna Rei

Porém, quando você tenta combinar o bloco de spoiler com um bloco de código, não funcionou bem.

Isso:

```
>! spoiler
>! 
>!     CODE CODE CODE
>!     CODE CODE CODE
```

Se torna isso:

> spoiler
>  
>      CODE CODE CODE
>      CODE CODE CODE

Tem como colocar blocos de código dentro de um bloco spoiler? Se se sim, como?

Tentei usar o triplo backtick, porém sem sucesso.

Isso:

````
>! spoiler
>! 
>! ```
>! CODE CODE CODE
>! CODE CODE CODE
>! ```
````

Se torna isso:

> spoiler
>  
>  
>  `CODE CODE CODE
>  CODE CODE CODE`

Porém não alcançou nem perto do resultado desejado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar as tags `<pre>` e `<code>` combinadas:

```
>! spoiler
>!
>! <pre><code> CODE CODE CODE
>! CODE CODE CODE</code></pre>
```

Resultado:

> spoiler
>
> ```
>  CODE CODE CODE
>  CODE CODE CODE
> ```

---

Exemplo com algum código aleatório:

```
>! spoiler
>!
>! <pre><code>  if x = 'abc':
>!      print('ok')
>!  for x in lista:
>!      if x > 10:
>!          print(x)</code></pre>
```

Resultado:

> spoiler
>
> ```
>   if x = 'abc':
>       print('ok')
>   for x in lista:
>       if x > 10:
>           print(x)
> ```

O detalhe é que se você deixar a abertura e fechamento das tags em uma linha separada, são adicionadas linhas em branco no início e fim do bloco de código:

```
>! spoiler
>!
>! <pre><code>
>!  if x = 'abc':
>!      print('ok')
>!  for x in lista:
>!      if x > 10:
>!          print(x)
>! </code></pre>
```

Resultado:

> spoiler
>
> ```
>   if x = 'abc':
>       print('ok')
>   for x in lista:
>       if x > 10:
>           print(x)
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Acho que isso pode te ajudar, apesar de não ser perfeito...

Opção usando `<pre>` e `<br>`

```
>! spoiler<br>CODE CODE CODE 
>! <pre>Line 1 &lt;span&gt;
>!Line 2</pre>
```

> spoiler
> CODE CODE CODE
>
> ```
> Line 1 <span>
> Line 2
> ```

Opção com `<br>` sem indentação

```
>! spoiler<br>CODE CODE CODE &lt;span&gt;<br>CODE CODE CODE
```

> spoiler
> CODE CODE CODE <span>
> CODE CODE CODE

E se vc quiser com indentação pode usar algum HTML entity

```
>! spoiler<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CODE CODE CODE &lt;span&gt;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CODE CODE CODE
```

> spoiler
>     CODE CODE CODE <span> 
>     CODE CODE CODE