# Como crio blocos de conteúdo extensíveis e recolhíveis?

Tags: suporte, novo-recurso, formatação

Por exemplo, soube que no github pode-se criar com `<detail>` um bloco de conteúdo que começa recolhido e pode ser extendido ao clicar em algo [(link)](https://docs.github.com/pt/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/organizing-information-with-collapsed-sections). Também vi o uso do recurso na ajuda do markdown para encurtar seções longas mas não uma seção que ensina a aplicar [(link)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). É possível criar seções de conteúdo omitíveis e exibíveis? Inclusive com códigos e até títulos? Se sim, como? Se não, será implementado? Boa tarde.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não existe algo assim, o equivalente aproximado atual é o "Revelar spoiler", que pode ser usado assim:

```
>! foo bar
```

Resultado:

> foo bar

Infelizmente não funciona com blocos de código, o máximo possível seria mesclar `<pre><code>` com o spoiler:

> ```
> foo bar baz
> foo bar baz
> foo bar baz
> foo bar baz
> foo bar baz
> foo bar baz
> foo bar baz
> ```

O problema é que o scroll não recolhe (a altura não se ajustará).

Até o momento a [especificação](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/) também parece não apresentar algo que resolverá essa necessidade.

Note que se for apresentar HTML, CSS e/ou JavaScript, você pode usar o *Stack Snippet* e esconder os blocos marcando a opção *Esconder trecho de código por padrão* (desde que seja um código válido para o *Stack Snippet* e siga o [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)):

[image: Stack Snippet recolhido]

Exemplo:

```js
javascript
```

```css
css
```

```html
html
```

Comment: @bfavaretto :) pelo jeito nem a especificação tem algo que servirá melhor https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/

Comment: Podiam implementar isso ou deixar funcionar a tag [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details).

Comment: **Nota:** apesar de entender como um recurso interessante, penso que se uma resposta precisar de códigos grandes, ou algo assim, talvez a resposta esteja fugindo do propósito do site.

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, poderia ter um "allow-tag" por site (deve até ter, mas só do lado dos CMs)

Comment: Sobre colocar código no bloco de spoiler: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7727/112052

Comment: Ok. Até então, é isso.